# WPF dispatcher performance from Multiple background threads by DispatcherPriority

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm doing some ground work performance testing on new implementation of DataCache. I understand the concept like buffering the task into batch or giving some leap time before before pushing gui update task to dispatcher.

This is just a testing purpose to put huge amount of task to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in a very short period of time as below.

```
    private ICommand _onStartBackgroundProcessCommand;
    public ICommand OnStartBackgroundProcessCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _onStartBackgroundProcessCommand ?? (_onStartBackgroundProcessCommand = new RelayCommand(p => 
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    {
                        UpdateDummyString(i);
                    }
                }
                )));
        }
    }

    public void UpdateDummyString(int runningIndex)
    {
        UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            DummyString = runningIndex.ToString();
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }

    public string DummyString
    {
        get { return _dummyString; }
        set
        {
            _dummyString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I found that the gui still remain very responsive even if i push huge amount of work in the background.

I'm wondering most of the problem for frequent background update can be solved simply by setting the correct the DispatcherPriority. I mean just keep the DispatcherPriority to background for datastream update and set the DispatcherPriority to normal if the gui update task is triggered by user actions.

Am i missing anything here ?

Comment: check the async-await concept for UI responsiveness

Comment: I believe my implementation is already a async update process. It's not about excuiting task in the background. I'm investigating the problem of "queuing up UI update task too frequently to dispatcher" will cause responsiveness problem to GUI.

Comment: async is more to the UI responsiveness then just a process in background. I would recommend you to check for async usage UI responsiveness.

Comment: this might be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCW_eJA2FeY

Comment: Com'on ... that's just a wrapper of Task.StartNew and ContinueWith. So, Let's just say the project is targetting to .NET 4.0. Would that be easier ?